# How to make div 100% of display height when I have to exclude the Navbar

Tags: html, css

One question I have a div below a navbar. I want that the div has 100% of the remaining space and add a nice padding as Frame around it. It should not be scroll able. Also I cant bind the navbar somehow because in the project its completely different component.

I try to simplify my code.

```css
nav {
  min-height: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.take-page-height {
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: red;
  /* added for demonstration */
}

.welcome-div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: green;
  background-clip: border-box;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

<nav>Hello world</nav>
<div class="take-page-height">
  <div class="welcome-div">
    <div class="col-md-12 center-text">
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The question is how I can make the div 100% of remaining space.

1. is not scrollable
2. cant integrate the navbar for example in a gridsystem
3. A nice padding frame is around the container.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/25098486#25098486  ... flex-grow and min-height or height + flex is missing on body grid can do it too. position:relative has no use here ;) to include padding and size, use box-sizing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: The answer that I found. Need a body or some sort of element that contains both header and the rest. I want only from the perspective of the container to fill up the remaining space. And not that I have to frame all elements. Because my structure is already to complex.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you: [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Basically you should use flexbox to make the div grow and fill up the rest of the page. Are you familiar with flex box? If not you can read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: this deserves to be a comment. devellop this answer with the source to make a working snippet at least ;) or turn it into a comment ;

Comment: thanks but, this does not exclude the header. I even found that maybe a javascript solution is possible so not sure what to do.